# Missing Messages from chat.db

Tags: messages, python, mysql, database

Hi so I can't currently create a minimum reproducible example but I am missing texts that I know I sent and appear in the search on the iMessage app but aren't in chat.db

My python code below

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db = 'chatCopy.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()

cmd1 = 'SELECT * \
            FROM message \
            '

c.execute(cmd1)
messages = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns = list(map(lambda x: x[0], c.description)))

messages[messages['text'].apply(lambda x : 'Maybe like Sherlock' in x if x else False)].shape
>>>(0, 68)
```

Then when searching in iMessage

[image: (I am on spotty wifi and can add a screen shot later from the messages app on Mac but basically this is a direct quote with 1 search hit that does successfully pop up.)]

Finally when going to `~/Library/Messages/Archive/` the messages do exist.  (This is what I assume the messages app is actually searching.)

I have somewhat noticed that this is only happening with older messages although I cannot confirm that this only happens to older messages.